# How to add text in particular block of canvas

Tags: php, html, canvas

I would like to add text in a Rectangle  block of my canvas.Please let me know how can I do this, My code is Below

```
 <html>
        <title>Canvas app</title>
        <head>
        <style>
        #canvas_ract{
            border:1px solid black;
        } 
        </style>
        <script>
              window.onload =function(){
                var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas_ract');
                var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
                              //ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000bb";
                            ctx.arc(200,100,100,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.font="30px Arial";
                ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
                ctx.fillStyle="pink";
                ctx.fillRect(30,40,200,100);
                             }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="canvas_ract" width="500"height="500"><canvas>

        </body>
    </html>
```

and also tell me if there is any good way to get more knowledge about this canvas api

Answer (score 1):

If your question was how to add the text "Hello World!" inside the pink rectangle the answer would be to inverse the order of your fillText and fillRectangle calls. Something like :

```
ctx.fillStyle="pink";
ctx.fillRect(30,40,200,100);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",35,70, 200,100);
```

When using canvas you need to know that everything you draw is stacked on top of the previous drawing. You can see it like the css z-index property. Meaning that the last canvas statement will always be  on top.

You can see an example of text on top of a rectangle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nc6bVluTq7yFJRJDKsQy?p=preview)

And as schopy said http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#text is a good reference or a more technical one https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas

**UPDATE** : How to add an image

First you need to create an image object programmatically and thenm use the drawImage function. This can be done like that :

```
var img = new Image();
//Link to the image as if it where an img tag in your dom tree
img.src = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-walk-icon.png';
img.onload = function () {
  //Wait for the image to be loaded and continue with the canvas manipulation
  ctx.drawImage(img, 120,40);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", 35, 70, 200, 100);
}
```

[Here is a 2nd example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nc6bVluTq7yFJRJDKsQy?p=preview) with an image in it